# Is it good practice to have one service that interacts with an individual entity, and one service that interacts with a collection of entities?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

Let's say we have a `User` entity. Should I have two smaller services (`User` and `Users`)? Or  one larger service that deals with both a collection of `User`s and an individual `User`? If it is the latter, is it best practice to name the service `User` or `Users`?

Answer (score 1):

I use one service per entity that houses the collection, methods used by the entity collection controller, and methods used by the individual entity's controller.  This works for my team as  we follow the repository pattern in our server code.  I save the collection in the service because it is accessed often, and parts of the collection are nice to share in other area's like to keep a count in the menu, or create a relational list in another controller.  The individual entity is typically only accessed by the controller for the view, and can be disposed of when the route is changed as long as the list item in the controller was updated if the entity was changed.

The only time I used separate services was one edge case where the customer wanted an entity to save state if the route was changed without persisting the entity to the server or cache.  The entity needed to be saved somewhere so that was reason enough to create a service for the individual entity.

I do use a separate service per entity to manage http requests.  So each entity does have two services, one to manage the collection and all crud+ functionality, and the other for http for separation of concerns.